# Devise SessionsController#create signs user in after return

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using devise for authentication.  I want to override the `Devise::SessionsController#create` action to prevent the user from being signed in when they haven't activated their account:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  before_action :set_user, only: :create

  def create
    if @user && !@user.activated?
      return redirect_to(new_activation_token_path) # prevent the user from logging in
    else
      super # default behavior
    end
  end

private
  def set_user
    @user = (params[:user].blank?) ? 
      User.new : 
      User.find_by(email: params[:user][:email])
  end
end
```

It's my understanding that `return redirect_to(some_path)` would cause the action to return early, but it seems like it's not—the user is still being signed in. What am I missing here?  How do I prevent the user from being signed in based on some condition?

Comment: Check out the confirmation module provided by devise, would it meet your needs? [http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Confirmable](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Confirmable)

Answer (score 0):

In the `User` model, override `#active_for_authentication?` (Taken from [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Customize-user-account-status-validation-when-logging-in))

```
# Devise model
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def active_for_authentication?
    activated? && super
  end
end
```